# How can I wrap each character from a text node in a <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I want to split a string value in a single digits and `wrap()` it in `<li></li>`. I am trying to achieve this goal but fail to do this following is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var str = $('#number').html();
    var spl = str.split('');
    var len = spl.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {

      if (i <= len) {
        $('#number').wrap('<li>' + spl[0] + '</li>')

      }
      i++;

    }, 200)
  })
</script>

<div id="number">123456 as</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var str = $('#number').html();
    var spl = str.split('');
    var len = spl.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){

        if(i <= len )
        {
            $('#number').append('<li>'+spl[i]+'</li>')

            }
        i++;

        },200)
})
</script>
```

reference **[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

Comment: Thanks for help Rituraj but why not wrap()

Comment: you make new html and insert in a container so for this append is good     you can also use html() in jquery but by this previous html remove so use append  you can also use wrap but i prefer append you can see here for wrap http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

here `spl[0]` this always selects the first index of array (split)... use `spl[i]`

try this

```
 var str = $('#number').html();
 var spl = str.split('');
 var len = spl.length;
 var i = 0;

 setInterval(function () {

 if (i < len) {
     if (spl[i] != " ") { //checking for the space here
         $('#number').append('<li>' + spl[i] + '</li>')
                   //-^^^^^^----------^^^^^^-----here
     }
 }
 i++;

 }, 200)
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kUq6g/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to move each character from the text into a `<li>`, then here's an alternative solution that splits the text nodes in place and wraps them:

```
//- Get a reference to the raw text node
var txt = $('#number').contents()[0];

setTimeout(function repeat(){
    if (txt.nodeValue.length) {
        //- Split the text node after the first character
        txt = txt.splitText(1);

        //- txt is now the latter text node, so wrap the former with a <li>
        $(txt.previousSibling).wrap('<li>');

        //- Rinse and repeat
        setTimeout(repeat, 200)
    }
},200);
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/9wRbe/

Also, I swapped your `setInterval` for a `setTimeout` because your timer would have run indefinitely, whereas this stops when the sequence is complete.

Here's one splitting backwards for fun:

```
var txt = $('#number').contents()[0];

setTimeout(function (){
    if (txt.nodeValue.length) {
        $(txt.splitText(txt.nodeValue.length - 1)).wrap('<li>');

        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 200)
    }
},200);
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/9wRbe/1/

**See also:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text.splitText

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str = $('#number').html();
    var spl = str.split('');
    var len = spl.length;
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){

        if(i <= len )
        {
            if(spl[i] !== undefined && spl[i] !== " "){
                $('#number').wrap('<li>'+spl[i]+'</li>')
            }
        }
        i++;
    },200);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5Brh/1/

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT wrap with html content only html tag is allowed in wrap()

here is your ans [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckZ9M/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var str = $('#number').html();
    var spl = str.split(' ');
    var len = spl.length;
    var i = 0;


        if(i <= len )
        {
            $('#number').wrap('<li id="dd"> </li>')

            }
        i++;

       $('#number').text(spl[0]);
})
```